# Can someone explain me the difference between these two queries [Select a.Name From account a] and [Select Name From account ]

Tags: apex, soql, query

Why do we need to create instance of an object in an query and what difference does it make from normal query.
I tried running these query and couldn't notice a difference

I was going through some old code and found this method

public static List getEmailTemplates()
{

List templates = [Select e.Name, e.Id From EmailTemplate e ];

return templates;
}

My question is why not use a Normal query instead of this alias

Comment: You are talking about aliases (more commonly seen in SQL) In SOQL aliases are typically used for aggregate values. See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_alias.htm). They are used to shorten the text.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why did you not [edit] the question to clarify? Adding a comment about it is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

Alias notation in SOQL statements are used to distinguish different object used in a single SOQL Statement. To establish the alias, first we should identify the object and then specify the alias.

In Salesforce SOQL, we have some reserved keywords which are not used as alias names. They are:

**AND, ASC, DESC, EXCLUDES, FIRST, FROM, GROUP, HAVING, IN, INCLUDES, LAST, LIKE, LIMIT, NOT, NULL, NULLS, OR, SELECT, USING, WHERE, WITH**

You can use an alias for any field or aggregated field in a SELECT statement in a SOQL query. Use a field alias to identify the field when you’re processing the query results in your code.

ex: `SELECT COUNT(Id) recordCount FROM Account` allows you to alias the result of the aggregation from it's default `expr0` to `recordCount`

Refer the [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_alias.htm)

SOQL statement we can fetch data using Alias notation from different objects.

ex: `SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact C, Con.Account Acc WHERE Acc.Name = 'Genepoint'`

As shown above, **C** is the alias name for Contact and **Acc** is the alias name for Account object. It will fetch contacts which are related to account name as `Genepoint`

**Conclusion:**

SOQL has very limited aliasing support. In most contexts you cannot use alias fields.

Comment: Ok the main question here is a bit different 
I was going through some old code and found this method 

public static List<EmailTemplate> getEmailTemplates()
    {
        List<EmailTemplate> templates = [Select e.Name, e.Id From EmailTemplate e ];
        return templates;
    }


My question is why not use Normal query instead of this alias